# abstract classes and templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I do have some general data type and some derived type(s):

```
class abstract_data { virtual void foo() {}; };
class derived_data : public abstract_data { void foo() {} };
```

I want to write some classes that work on that data. What I would **like** to do is:

```
class abstract_worker {
public:
    virtual void apply(abstract_data&) = 0;
};

class derived_worker : public abstract_worker {
public:
    void apply(derived_data&) {} ;
};
```

This is not working, because the compiler asks me to implement `void apply(abstract_data&)`. I see two alternatives.

1.alternative:

```
class abstract_worker {
public:
    virtual void apply(abstract_data&) = 0;
};

class derived_worker : public abstract_worker {
public:
    void apply(abstract_data& data) {
        derived_data& internal_data = dynamic_cast<derived_data&>(data);
    }
};
```

2. alternative:

```
template<class DATA_TYPE>
class abstract_worker {
public:
    virtual void apply(DATA_TYPE&) = 0;
};

class derived_worker : public abstract_worker<derived_data> {
public:
    void apply(derived_data&) { }
};
```

I don't like both of them. In the 1st alternative the parameter is declared as `abstract_data&` even though it really needs to be `derived_data&`.

In the 2nd alternative it gets lost that the parameter is of type `abstract_data&`. This is even more problematic if `apply(abstract_data&)` is not pure virtual, but uses some functionality of `abstract_data`. You run in the situtation where `abstract_data&` is implicitely required as `DATA_TYPE`, but not explicitely declared as such.

However, I do want to keep the type relationships.

Is there another way? If not which one would you prefer?

Comment: The first one fits the general philosophy of virtual functions.  The second does not.  It is hard to imagine why it might both be useful to have that as a virtual function and to have the second hierarchy.  When you want that kind of templating, that is usually instead of virtual, not mixed that way.

Comment: Your preferred `derived_worker` does not conform to the Liskov Substitution Principle, indicating bad design. How come `derived_worker` IS AN `abstract_worker` if all `abstract_workers` can work with all `abstract_data`, and `derived_worker` cannot?

Comment: This isn't a place to use virtual functions. They're for when you don't know the dynamic type of an object. Your derived worker knows it wants a derived worker.

Comment: @Angew `abstract_worker` can work with `derived_data`. However `derived_data` is richer than `abstract_data` and `derived_worker` relies on that

Comment: @Michael Yes, but by virtue of the function signature, `abstract_worker` can work with *any* `abstract_data`, even one which is not `derived_data`. Therefore, if `derived_worker` cannot work with *any* `abstract_data` as well, then by definition, it IS NOT AN `abstract_worker`.

Comment: @Angew I don't understand this. An animal herder can work with any animals, cats or cows. A cowboy works only with cows and not with cats and is therefore not an animal herder?

Comment: @Michael Yes, per standard object-oriented design principles, that is the case. Read up on the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Let's take your animal handler example. I am a program which receives a reference to an animal handler. I tell it to handle some cats, as animal handlers can handle cats (that's how you defined an animal handler). I may not even know that cowboys exist; I have no reason to expect the call to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You might use static assert to prevent `DATA_TYPE` not inheriting from `abstract_data`:
    #include

```
class abstract_data { virtual void foo() {}; };
class derived_data : public abstract_data { void foo() {} };
class faulty_data { void foo() {} };

template<class DATA_TYPE>
class abstract_worker {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<abstract_data, DATA_TYPE>::value, "DATA_TYPE does not inherit from abstract_data");

public:
    virtual void apply(DATA_TYPE&) = 0;
};

class derived_worker : public abstract_worker<derived_data> {
public:
    void apply(derived_data&) {}
};

class faulty_worker : public abstract_worker<faulty_data> {
public:
    void apply(faulty_data&) {}
};
```

Output while compiling:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test_Call, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1><PROJ_PATH>\source.cpp(9): error C2338: DATA_TYPE does not inherit from abstract_data
1>  <PROJ_PATH>\source.cpp(20): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'abstract_worker<faulty_data>' being compiled
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```